# Point-sampling rasters using R?

Tags: raster, r, point, sampling

I need to be able to sample many raster files (imported from GeoTIFFs) using a previously defined set of spatial points, using R.  What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "extract" function in the raster package will extract raster values to points for a stack or single raster.

Comment: This answer is perfect.  Should it perhaps be added to the question that my question has been tagged as duplicating?